# how to desable one jquery function by another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two different function in my code
function A: show/hide login, signup form

```js
$(document).ready(function ()
   {
      //function to hide/show signup form
    $("#signup_form").hide();
    $("#signup").click(function ()
    {
     $("#login_form").hide();
     $("#signup_form").show();
    });
    $("#login").click(function ()
    {
     $("#signup_form").hide();
     $("#login_form").show();
    });
        
        //function to check email_id in db using ajax
         $(#email_id).(function()
  {
   var email_id = $(this).val();
   $.ajax({
    url:"check.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{email_id:email_id},
    dataType:"text",
    success:function(html)
    {
    $('#availability').html(html);
    }
   });
  });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Function B: search email_id in db using ajax

now my problem is when i call function A, function B also called together

Comment: Does this code even compile? `$(#email_id)` is not valid JavaScript.

Comment: This doesn't compile. It is missing code.

Comment: function `B` is called when you called function `A` because you show/hide the element `#email_id ` , try to change this selector `$('#email_id")` to be on keyup or focus or click , to do this function only when did this action

Comment: still no work

Comment: is there any method to disable function B by calling function A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have to do either one of them that is mentioned below:

1. add any event on function B on which this will be called. For eg,

   $(#email_id).on('click',function()

   {
           // put your code.

   ```
    });
   ```
2. Or, convert function B into plain function.

function B (){

//put your code.

});